# How to, in SmallTalk, programmatically resize the tableinterface column sizes dynamically?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, visualworks

I have a table that I am dynamically populating, and so, I do not know hoa many columns are in my table but I would like to resize as needed.

Comment: What sort of table are we talking about? A specific/custom Smalltalk class? Reading from HTML? The question as it is does not give me much to go by. What approaches have you tried and what are the problems you're encountering?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking visualworks (your choice of tags is confusing), I assume you are asking about a DataSet; there, look for the columnDescription.